# R - Create a column in my dataframe that contains the name of each list (in a list of lists object) based on overlap between each other

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df3) and a list of lists (l3):

```
l1<-c("GO:0071363", "GO:0070848", "GO:0007169", "GO:0007167")

l2 <-c("GO:0016567", "GO:0070647", "GO:0032446")
l3 <- list(l1,l2)
names(l3) <- c("GROUP1","GROUP2")

##############################print my list
> l3
$GROUP1
[1] "GO:0071363" "GO:0070848" "GO:0007169" "GO:0007167"
$GROUP2
[1] "GO:0016567" "GO:0070647" "GO:0032446"
```

##################################################

```
df1 <- structure(list(geneSet = c("GO:0070848", "GO:0071363", "GO:0007169", 
                    "GO:0007167"), description = c("response to growth factor", "cellular response to growth factor stimulus", 
                     "transmembrane receptor protein tyrosine kinase signaling pathway", 
                     "enzyme linked receptor protein signaling pathway")), row.names = c(10L, 
                     16L, 177L, 219L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(geneSet = c("GO:0070647", "GO:0016567", "GO:0032446"
), description = c("protein modification by small protein conjugation or removal", 
                   "protein ubiquitination", "protein modification by small protein conjugation"
)), row.names = c(13L, 15L, 25L), class = "data.frame")
df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)
######################print my dataframe
> df3
       geneSet                                                      description
10  GO:0070848                                        response to growth factor
16  GO:0071363                      cellular response to growth factor stimulus
177 GO:0007169 transmembrane receptor protein tyrosine kinase signaling pathway
219 GO:0007167                 enzyme linked receptor protein signaling pathway
13  GO:0070647     protein modification by small protein conjugation or removal
15  GO:0016567                                           protein ubiquitination
25  GO:0032446                protein modification by small protein conjugation
```

First, I need to match each string located on my geneSet column with this same string on list of lists.
After that, I need to create a additional column in my original df3 (named "cluster") that contain the name of each list that contains the respective geneSet. My output would be:

```
> df3
       geneSet                                                      description cluster
10  GO:0070848                                        response to growth factor  GROUP1
16  GO:0071363                      cellular response to growth factor stimulus  GROUP1
177 GO:0007169 transmembrane receptor protein tyrosine kinase signaling pathway  GROUP1
219 GO:0007167                 enzyme linked receptor protein signaling pathway  GROUP1
13  GO:0070647     protein modification by small protein conjugation or removal  GROUP2
15  GO:0016567                                           protein ubiquitination  GROUP2
25  GO:0032446                protein modification by small protein conjugation  GROUP2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if we `stack` the `list` to a two column data.frame and then do a `merge` (in `base R`)

```
merge(df3, stack(l3), by.x = 'geneSet', by.y = 'values')
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, `enframe` the `list` to a two column `tibble`, `unnest` the `list` column and do a join

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
enframe(l3, value = 'geneSet', name= 'cluster') %>% 
     unnest(c(geneSet)) %>%
     right_join(df3)
```